# Uploading image to third party service using alamofire and auth token

Tags: swift, http, alamofire

I have been trying to upload my image to a third party website using their api and alamofire to get some information back regarding the image that has been uploaded. I have to pass the auth token in with the request to get access to their resources, here is the instruction they have provided,

"Image should be specified by its url or uploaded with multipart form by parameter 'data'. You should use, respectively, GET and POST methods."

I have been trying to implement the upload method in 5 different ways but none of them seem to work I get a responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 \"Invalid value around character 2.\" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 2.}))" error back here is one of the functions that takes care of the upload:

```
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [ "Authorization": "Bearer \(authToken)" ]
    let URL = try! URLRequest(url: "url", method: .post, headers: headers)

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "signImg", fileName: "picture.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    }, with: URL, encodingCompletion: {
        encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            // hide progressbas here
            print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")
        }
    })
```

I also don't understand the meaning of the parameters used to append the multipartformdata such as withName, filetype, mimeType.
I would really appreciate if you could attach an explanation with the solution.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No I haven't, do you have one? @HSWarraich: